# Missing Visual Studio 2013 Templates

Tags: c++, graphics, fbx, visual-studio

Visual Studio 2013 is missing the installed templates related to graphics, **SPECIFICALLY** the fbx scene template.. Why is this so? And where do I get them ?

Comment: in fact the whole graphic template section is not present at all

Comment: What OS are you using? What edition of Visual Studio? And do you mean 'project template' or some other kind of template or do you mean 'build customization files'?

Comment: win 8.1 with visual studio 2013 ultimate, i mean the pre_installed project templates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help:
From [MSDN: How to: Restore Default Project Templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms247116(v=vs.100).aspx):

> If you accidentally delete the default project templates that are included with Visual Studio, you can use this procedure to restore them without reinstalling Visual Studio.
>
> **To restore the default project templates**
>   In the command prompt, navigate to the location of devenv.exe. This file is located in \Common7\IDE.
>   Note:If you are running Windows Vista or Windows 7, you must open the command prompt as an administrator by right-clicking the command prompt and then clicking Run as administrator.
>
> Type "devenv /installvstemplates" and press Enter.
>   Note:If you are using an Express Edition of Visual Studio, type "Express /installvstemplates" where  is either VB or VCS for Visual Basic and Visual C#, respectively.
>
> If this procedure does not restore the default templates, reinstall Visual Studio.

In case you want to download it, from [MSDN:How to: Find and Install Templates Located Online](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms185306(v=vs.100).aspx)

> You can find and install online project templates from the New Project dialog box. Each project template represents a type of project that Visual Studio can create for you. You can find and install online item templates from the Add New Item dialog box. You can also install online project and item templates from Extension Manager.
>
> **To install project templates from the New Project dialog box**
>   On the File menu, click New, and then click Project. The New Project >dialog box opens.
>   In the left pane, click Online Templates and expand the Templates list.
>   In the Templates list, select the category of templates to search for
>   -- OR --
>   Type one or more keywords in the Search box.
>   A list of templates appears in the middle pane.
>   Note:The search function ignores the selected category and returns results with the given keywords in their titles or descriptions. Partial words are included but all keywords must be present in the result.
>   Select a template from the list.
>   Information about the selected template appears in the right pane.
>   Double-click the template to install
>   -- OR --
>   Fill in the fields at the bottom of the window and click OK to install the template and create a new project.
>
> **To install item templates from the Add New Item dialog box**
>   In Solution Explorer, right-click the current project, select Add, and New Item.
>   The Add New Item dialog box opens.
>   In the left pane, click Online Templates and expand the Templates list.
>   In the Templates list, select the category of templates to search for
>   -- OR --
>   Type one or more keywords in the Search box.
>   A list of templates appears in the middle pane.
>   Note:The search function ignores the selected category and returns results with the given keywords in their titles or descriptions. Partial words are included but all keywords must be present in the result.
>   Select a template from the list.
>   Information about the selected template appears in the right pane.
>   Double-click the template to install
>
> **To install templates from Extension Manager**
>   On the Tools menu, click Extension Manager….
>   In the left pane, click Online Gallery and expand the Templates list.
>   In the Templates list, select the category of templates to search for.
>   A list of templates appears in the middle pane.
>   -- OR --
>   Type one or more keywords in the Search box.
>   A list of extensions matching the search keywords appears in the middle pane.
>   Note:The search function ignores the selected category and returns results with the given keywords in their titles or descriptions. Partial words are included but all keywords must be present in the result.
>   Select a template from the list.
>   Information about the selected template appears in the right pane.
>   Double-click the template to install
>   -- OR --
>   Click Download.

Or try going to **FILE->NEW->FILE**.

Comment: unsuccessful but thanks, have microsoft removed some templates from their latest Visual Studio

Comment: @Brendy Donnelly Did you try reinstalling?

Comment: no I tried the repair installation option, these templates never existed on my version even before I updated from community to ultimate so I'm wondering maybe their not included in the 2013 edition??? Maybe there is a separate download or something??

Comment: @Brendy Donnelly I gues it is not removed http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2013/03/26/developing-an-app-with-the-visual-studio-3d-starter-kit-part-1-of-3.aspx